# validate string JSON java libraries vs online - different result

Tags: java, json

I have a method for validation string json in java.

I tried the best libraries like JsonSimple and gson and jackson. all of them has the same result that the json string is valid and below code is my jackson method for validation.

```
//jackson lib
public static boolean isValidJSON(final String json) throws IOException {
boolean valid = true;
try{ 
   objectMapper.readTree(json);

} catch(JsonProcessingException e){
 valid = false;
}

return valid;
}
```

I expect the online sites for validate json have same result for my code.

I checked my string in these sites

1. jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com
2. jsonlint.com
3. jsonformatter.org

Note: my string json in fact is invalid but i don't know why the code and sites result is not the same?

my json string:

```
{
   "hasError": false,
   "referenceNumber": "57050377",
"errorCode": 0,
"count": 0,
"ott": "5cd3db66e810db0b",
"result": {
    "id": 3551,
    "guilds": [{
        "id": 56,
        "code": "TRANSPORTATION_GUILD"
    }],
    "subscriptionCount": 0,
    "subscribed": false,
    "numOfComments": 0,
    "rate": {
        "rate": 0,
        "rateCount": 0
    },
    "fullAddress": "USA",
    "tags": [],
    "tagTrees": [],
    "active": false,
    "apiToken": "b9ea8244e34bb9f8d383467ad82",
    "numOfLike": 0,
    "numOfDislike": 0
  } 
 } 
   "id": 3551,
   "ssoId": "5884675",
   "apiToken": "b9ea80c804e34bb9f8d383467ad82",
 {  
 "count": 0,
 "ott": "2558074f8d18f49e",
 "result": {        
     "email": "pos_psp@ptest.land",
     "fullAddress": "CHINA",
     "tags": [],
     "tagTrees": [],
     "active": false,
     "apiToken": "0a4a31d1fe5c457785145fe7f97bc26e",
     "numOfLike": 0,
     "numOfDislike": 0,
     "username": "pos_psp"
   }
 }
 "id": 3552,
 "userId": 1357729
 "username": "pos_psp"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON parsers only read the first root value of the input.

E.g. with the following JSON text, only the first object with field `foo` will be parsed, and then parsing stops, so it doesn't see the rest, which can then be anything.

```json
{
  "foo": 42
}
{
  "bar": 666
}
```

To validate the JSON text, and to verify that no extra content is present, you can use the underlying Jackson parser, instead of the high-level `ObjectMapper`.

```
public static void validateJSON(String json) throws IOException {
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
    try (JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(json)) {
        if (jsonParser.nextToken() == null)
            throw new IOException("No JSON root element");
        if (jsonParser.skipChildren().nextToken() != null) {
            JsonLocation loc = jsonParser.getTokenLocation();
            throw new IOException("Multiple JSON root elements" +
                                  " at line " + loc.getLineNr() +
                                  ", column " + loc.getColumnNr());
        }
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
public static void test(String json) {
    try {
        validateJSON(json);
        System.out.println("Valid");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid: " + e);
    }
}
```

```
test("");
test("{}");
test("{ \"foo\": 42 }");
test("{\n" +
     "  \"foo\": 42\n" +
     "}\n" +
     "{\n" +
     "  \"bar\": 666\n" +
     "}");
test(Files.readString(Paths.get("test.json")));
```

The last is reading a file with the JSON from the question.

*Output*

```
Invalid: java.io.IOException: No JSON root element
Valid
Valid
Invalid: java.io.IOException: Multiple JSON root elements at line 4, column 1
Invalid: java.io.IOException: Multiple JSON root elements at line 29, column 4
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say that all the libraries that you've tested (jackson, gson, etc.) have the same result, what exactly do you mean? The same error message, the same exception class, the same stacktrace? Please post the result of the check in the question so that our colleagues could provide a better answer.

When you call the sites you've mentioned in the question, no-one guarantees that in the backend your sample json gets processed by one of the libraries you've tested, no-one guarantees even that the backend of the site is written in Java / any JVM language so that potentially these json libraries could not be even accessible for the developers of those sites.

One way or another, every library java based or not has its own algorithm of parsing the json object, so the errors can also be slightly different. That's the reason that you have different results, and its OK.

Comment: i mean that all sites has the same error "Multiple JSON root elements Error" but all the lib return json is valid